# How to assign a value from a list, from user inputed code, to a variable

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say I have two lists A and B of prices, where each price corresponds to a code. Like A1 is $2.50, A2 is $3.50, etc.

The user inputs the codes of the items they want. From there I just need the prices of the items they sellected assigned to variables. How do I set the inputed code to the respective cost?

```
items = [str(x) for x in input("What items would you like?").split()]
item1 = items[0]
item2 = items[1]
A = [2.50, 3.50, 4.50, 5.00, 6.50]
B = [2.00, 3.00, 1.50, 5.50, 3.50]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first letter of each user input corresponds to the name of the list you pick from (i.e. as you said, "A1" => `A[0]`), then you'll have to use the reviled `eval` in your solution.

But first, let's talk input format. Here's what I recommend:

```
selections = map(lambda w: (w[0], int(w[1:])), input('> ').split())
```

This gives you a list of list (well, map object) of pairs: the first element of which is the list name, the second of which is the index.

Now we can grab our data from the respective lists:

```
for list_name, index in selections:
    print(eval(list_name)[index-1])  # -1 since input is 1-indexed
```

[demo](https://repl.it/Jxg8/1)